# WPF MVVM Change GUI after clicking Item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I currently try to visualize an RSS feed. I have created 2 objects: `FeedChannel` and `FeedElement`. The `FeedChannel` may contain `FeedElement`s.

This feed may have multiple channels, which will be displayed like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Feed, IsAsync=True}" x:Name="ListFeed">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChannelClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListFeed, Path=SelectedItem}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" Source="{Binding ImageLink}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="50"/>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublicationDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Thin"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>                           
                    </StackPanel>                       
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The `ChannelClickCommand` will save the clicked Channel into the `ActiveChannel` property. From my view, I should now access the `ActiveChannel` and display the `FeedElement`s inside it.

That's all quite easily done, but I struggle in finding the correct approach for the following:

Given that the User first sees all Channels (and only Channels!), he may now click one of them and then all Elements will be displayed (no Channels are visible anymore). He may go back to view all Channels with a Button-click or something similar.

I thought about using Stackpanels and turning them visible/collapsed depending on what's needed, but is there a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that from a UI/UX point of view having the channels and elements in the same list is the best way to handle it. But to answer your question, you can have a look at the `DataTemplateSelector` property or you could use the `DataType` property on the `DataTemplate` element.

Without getting into too much details (a little search on the website will give you all required info), here is a solution with the `DataType` property:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Feed, IsAsync=True}" x:Name="ListFeed">          
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChannelClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ListFeed, Path=SelectedItem}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:FeedChannel}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" Source="{Binding ImageLink}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="50"/>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="ExtraBold" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublicationDate}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Thin"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>                           
                    </StackPanel>                       
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:FeedElement}">
                    <!-- Your data template for FeedElement -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ListBox.Resources>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Just replace the elements in your `Feed` property from the `ChannelClickCommand` and it should work fine.

Comment: I'll try it out today. Thank you!